# How to cast function arguments from tuple?

Tags: typescript

If I have a `tuple` how can I set it to a function for the input arguments?

```
type addArgs = [number, number]

const add = (a, b): number => {
  return a + b;
}
```

I tried something like this but it does not work:

```
type addArgs = [number, number]

const add = (...[a, b]: addArgs): number => {
  return a + b;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use [tuples in rest parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897):

```
type addArgs = [number, number]

const add = (...args: addArgs): number => {
  const [a, b] = args;
  return a + b;
}
add(1, 2);
```

We can't use de-structing in rest parameters unfortunately so we need to destructure in the function body and we do loose parameter names when calling, but this is the best that can be done